# Removing duplicate id in array in Swift

Tags: swift

I have an API with a duplicate primary key and null primary key. How will I remove those duplicate ids so that I can insert it in array and display it in tableview in Swift?

https://test-api.nevaventures.com/

This is the output of the above link:

```
{
  "id": 7,
  "name": "Raghuram Rajan",
  "skills": " Economist",
  "image": "https://teekhapan.files.wordpress.com/2012/08/raghuram-rajan.jpg?w=229&h=300"
},
{
  "skills": "Dancer"
},
{
  "id": 8,
  "name": "Raghuram Rajan",
  "skills": " Economist",
  "image": "https://teekhapan.files.wordpress.com/2012/08/raghuram-rajan.jpg?w=229&h=300"
},
{
  "id": 9,
  "name": "Kumar",
  "skills": "builder",
  "image": "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRKJk2hWltaMgJcf3QO6jIXOhmravSvIqEWAl9stEfszcjLNMVzPg"
},
{
  "id": 10,
  "name": "Ranjit",
  "skills": " builder",
  "image": "https://is1-2.housingcdn.com/4f2250e8/ee8bf39d2001fde419f82e0e6e90fb59/v5/_logo/solitare_ranjit_avenue1_bulara-ludhiana-solitare_colonizersand_builders.jpg"
},
{
  "id": 8,
  "name": "Raghuram Rajan",
  "skills": " Economist",
  "image": "https://teekhapan.files.wordpress.com/2012/08/raghuram-rajan.jpg?w=229&h=300"
},
{
  "id": 8,
  "name": "Raghuram Rajan",
  "skills": "Economist",
  "image": "https://teekhapan.files.wordpress.com/2012/08/raghuram-rajan.jpg?w=229&h=300"
},
```

Comment: Use a `Set` and then convert it back to an array?

Comment: no its not working it gives error i have checked it from google

Comment: You need to show your code and the details of the error you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Equatable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/equatable) in your class

```
class yourClass: Equatable {
    var id :Int = 0
    static func ==(lhs: yourClass, rhs: yourClass) -> Bool {
        return lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
}
```

then before appending new obj to your array check if it contains the obj or not.